# MySql / PHP only returning one result from database

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have seen a few topics on here about the same kind of problem, but I have not been able to come up with a solution as of yet so apologies for asking a similar question.

I am trying to recieve all the data from the database and echo out on to a page that will display all results.

Heres my code:

```
<?php

$event = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `events`");
while($get_event = mysql_fetch_array($event)) {
    $event_title        = $get_event['title'];
    $event_disc         = nl2br($get_event['discription']);
    $event_date         = $get_event['event_date'];
    $event_time         = $get_event['event_time'];
    $event_contname     = $get_event['contact_name'];
    $event_contnum      = $get_event['contact_num'];
    $event_username     = $get_event['username'];
    $event_number1      = $get_event['number1'];
    $event_line2        = $get_event['line2'];
    $event_city         = $get_event['city'];
    $event_postcode     = $get_event['postcode'];
    $event_country      = $get_event['country'];

}
echo '
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="funny-boxes funny-boxes-left-green">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 funny-boxes-img">
                <img alt="" src="' . $user_data['profile'] . '" style="width: 135px; height: 135px;" class="img-responsive">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                   <li><u>Contact Name:</u> <br>' . $event_contname . '</li>
                   <li><u>Num / Email:</u> <br>' . $event_contnum . '</li>
                   <li><u>Address:</u> <br>' . $event_number1 . ' <br> ' . $event_line2 . ' <br> ' . $event_city . ' <br> ' . $event_postcode . ' <br> ' . $event_country . ' </li>
                   <li><u>Date:</u> ' . $event_date .'</li>
                   <li><u>Time:</u> ' . $event_time .'</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h2>Destony Conferance 2014</h2>
                <p>' . $event_disc .'</p>
            </div>
        </div>                            
    </div>                    
</div>';

?>
```

Comment: move the `}` that closes the while after the last `</div>'`

Comment: It is highly recommended you switch from the deprecated mysql_ functions to either MySQLi or PDO functions.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put your echo statement inside of the loop. Otherwise it will only show the result of the last iteration of the loop:

```
while($get_event = mysql_fetch_array($event)) {
    $event_title        = $get_event['title'];
    $event_disc         = nl2br($get_event['discription']);
    $event_date         = $get_event['event_date'];
    $event_time         = $get_event['event_time'];
    $event_contname     = $get_event['contact_name'];
    $event_contnum      = $get_event['contact_num'];
    $event_username     = $get_event['username'];
    $event_number1      = $get_event['number1'];
    $event_line2        = $get_event['line2'];
    $event_city         = $get_event['city'];
    $event_postcode     = $get_event['postcode'];
    $event_country      = $get_event['country'];
    echo '
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="funny-boxes funny-boxes-left-green">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 funny-boxes-img">
                    <img alt="" src="' . $user_data['profile'] . '" style="width: 135px; height: 135px;" class="img-responsive">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                       <li><u>Contact Name:</u> <br>' . $event_contname . '</li>
                       <li><u>Num / Email:</u> <br>' . $event_contnum . '</li>
                       <li><u>Address:</u> <br>' . $event_number1 . ' <br> ' . $event_line2 . ' <br> ' . $event_city . ' <br> ' . $event_postcode . ' <br> ' . $event_country . ' </li>
                       <li><u>Date:</u> ' . $event_date .'</li>
                       <li><u>Time:</u> ' . $event_time .'</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h2>Destony Conferance 2014</h2>
                    <p>' . $event_disc .'</p>
                </div>
            </div>                            
        </div>                    
    </div>';
}
```

Comment: Im such an idiot :/ should have seen that, many thanks :)